# iphone-textfield releasing causes crash application

Tags: iphone

sir i am new in iphone i am creating UITextField using this code but when i am releasing this in dealloc application crashes. i want to make textfield by coding.
thanks in advance.

```
#import "TextField.h"

@implementation TextField
UILabel *label;
UITextField *textField;

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Create label
    label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 40);
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    label.text = @"";
    [self.view addSubview:label];
    [label release];

    // Initialization code
    textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 200, 300, 50)];
    textField.delegate = self;
    textField.placeholder = @"<Enter Text>";
    textField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    [self.view addSubview: textField];
    [textField release];
}

- (void)dealloc 
{
    [textField release];
    [label release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: can you post the crash on the console?

Answer (score 1):

You have already released your text field and label by :`[textField release]; ,[label release];`
 than you should not release it again in `dealloc` method.You are over releasing your text filed and label and that cause crash your application. Just remove it from `dealloc` method.

Answer (score 0):

you are using `[textField release]` in two places:
1) in ViewDidLoad
2) in dealloc method
You don't have to do this in two placed. Remove the `[textField release]` from viewDidLoad method.

This is because when you alloc an instance it retain count becomes `1` and when you are release it, the retain count becomes `0`. So again release the same instance is causing the crash.

Comment: sorry Emil but when we add textField in view by addSubview this makes textField retain count 2.thats why i am thinking that should we release it two times or one time. THANKS Emil for ur answer

Comment: when you add it to the view then yes it retain count will be 2. but when the view is released it releases all it subviews. So you only have to call release on textField for one time only.

Answer (score 0):

use this code... u have release label and text field two times ...

```
#import "TextField.h"

@implementation TextField
UILabel *label;
UITextField *textField;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

//Create label
label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 40);
label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
label.text = @"";
[self.view addSubview:label];
[label release];

// Initialization code
textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 200, 300, 50)];
textField.delegate = self;
textField.placeholder = @"<Enter Text>";
textField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
[self.view addSubview: textField];
[textField release];
}

@end
```

Comment: hey depeesh thanks,but pls tell me one thing when we add textfield in view textField's retain counter become 2.so to make retain counter one  we should releae it two times.

Comment: Objective-C uses two methods retain and release. In Objective-C each object has an internal counter that is used to keep track of all references used by the objects or object has. [object retain] increments the counter by 1 and [object release] decrements the counter by 1. When counter reaches to zero, dealloc is then called.